# ReactJS passing parent function into child created using map

Tags: reactjs, callback, parent-child, parent

I need to pass a parent function to a child component, but it doesn't seem to work due to the component being made in a map function.  Here is the code in question:

```
{this.state.recipes.map(function(a,index){
   return (<Recipe name={a.name} ingredients={a.ingredients} index={index} onClick={this.handleDelete}/>);
}
```

What is the best way to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not matter if it's component being made in a map function. I think that you just forgot to bind your function.

Your code should be like this

```
{this.state.recipes.map(function(a,index){
   return (<Recipe name={a.name} ingredients={a.ingredients} index={index} onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(this}/>);
}
```

You can also use arrow function, like this :

```
{this.state.recipes.map((a,index) => <Recipe name={a.name} ingredients={a.ingredients} index={index} onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(this}/>)}
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1377/).